# Time SQL Queries in Django

Tags: python, django

Is there a way to time sql queries in Django?

I know there's such thing in dj debug toolbar but I just need to display time on my web-page.

Since I can get a number of queries with:

```
len(connection.queries)
```

Maybe there's a similar way to get the time?

Answer (score 1):

You can show them in templates if you have **django.template.context_processors.debug** available in your template settings.

It attaches `sql_queries` list to template.

```
{% for query in sql_queries %}
    {{ query.time }}
{% endfor %}
```

Make sure that **DEBUG is True** in your settings and **request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR') in settings.INTERNAL_IPS**

Of course if you need something more [this](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/template/context_processors.py#L35) might help you.